# How to get the Path from an Uri id from a File?

Tags: java, android, windows, path, uri

I've tried to make a gallery out of the Videos created with my app.
When I click on one of the Thumbnail pictures I want to save the selected Video in my preferences.

To get the Thumbnails I wrote following code:

public void addVidsToArray()
    {

```
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID };
    String selection = MEDIA_DATA + " like ? ";
    String [] selectionArgs = new String[] {"%Bla%"};
    int columIndex;
    int id;

    Cursor videoCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, 
            selection, 
            selectionArgs, 
            null);


    videoCursor.moveToFirst();




    if(videoCursor.getCount() >= 1)
    {
        while (videoCursor.moveToNext()) {
            columIndex = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID) ;
            id = videoCursor.getInt(columIndex);                
            bitmaps.add(getThumbnail(id));
        }
    } 

}

public Bitmap getThumbnail(int id)
{
    ContentResolver crThumb = getContentResolver();
    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);

    curThumb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(curThumb, 300, 300, false);

    return curThumb;
}
```

I get the Tumbnail Pics due to the Uri id.
Now my Problem is how to bring that back to a normal path in a new File to saved it.

Following code is the the onClickListener which should save the video to the preferences.
But if I add the Uri to the new File, the file doesen't exsist.

I don't get it.

```
ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {               
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID };
            String selection = MEDIA_DATA + " like ? ";
            String [] selectionArgs = new String[] {"%Bla%"};
            int columIndex;
            int id1;

            Cursor videoCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, 
                    selection, 
                    selectionArgs, 
                    null);

            videoCursor.moveToFirst();

            if(videoCursor.getCount() >= 1)
            {
                while (videoCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    columIndex = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID) ;
                    id1 = videoCursor.getInt(columIndex);
                    daten.add(id1+"");                      
                }
            } 
            Log.v("vid id", ""+daten.get(position));

            int idData = Integer.parseInt(daten.get(position));

            saveVideo(idData);                              
        }
    });


}

public void saveVideo(int idData)
{
    String uriString = "content://media/external/video/media/" + idData;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
    File mVideoFile = new File(uriString);

    Log.v("testpfad", ""+ mVideoFile.getAbsolutePath() + " " + mVideoFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + " " + mVideoFile.exists());               
    mVideoFileLen = getDurationFromURI(uri);
    //setPreferences(mVideoFile.getAbsolutePath(), PICKED_VIDEO);
    //setPreferences(mVideoFileLen, VIDEO_LEN);     
    //startActivity(new Intent(this, Finished.class));  
}
```

In the end I need to create a File with the help of the Id from the Uri.

Comment: The column MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA contains the path to the file.

Comment: So I just have to make a managedQuery with "where Id = iData"?